# Send data from Django to java script(in Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-chrome

I have developed a chrome extension and I am inserting json data in mysql through django service. I want to send data from django to java script which is in chrome extension.
popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', documentEvents, false);

function myAction(fname,femail,fpassword) {
    var str = "name="+ fname.value +  "&email=" + femail.value + "&password=" + fpassword.value;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    alert(str);
    var theUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/?";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //alert(xmlhttp.readyState + " " + xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
            alert("entered");
        }
        else{
            alert("not entered");
        }

    };
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(str);

}

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var theUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/?";
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET",theUrl,true);
  xhttp.send();
}


function documentEvents() {
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit')
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', 
    function(event) {
        var formId = document.getElementById('test');
        var name = document.getElementById('name');
        var email = document.getElementById('email');
        var password = document.getElementById('password');
        myAction(name,email,password);
    });
}
```

views.py :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from .models import UserProfile
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    req = request.method
    t = request.GET
    print(req)
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    savedata = UserProfile(name=name,email=email,password=password)
    savedata.save()
    print('Hello %s %s %s' % (name, email, password))
    return HttpResponse('successfully inserted')
```

My problem is how to send data from views and how to get that data in java script.Is there a way to define java script method name in django views. Please provide me the clear code of views and java script

Comment: Surely you just need to return the actual data you want to show from your view, rather than "successfully inserted"?

Comment: successfully inserted will be displayed in the localhost page... I want to display the simple string data in the extension which has been sent from the django views to the javascript